# Why some dates being shown as BST and some as GMT when formatting Date?

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone, simpledateformat

I have following 2 input strings:

```
String string1 = "2017-01-30T13:00:00+0000"
String string2 = "2018-06-23T16:00:00+0000"
```

For string1 I am getting following as a date when I do:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date startDate = formatter.parse(string1);
```

result - `Mon Jan 30 13:00:00 GMT 2017`

But when I do the same for string2 I get the following in my debugger:

```
Sat Jun 23 17:00:00 BST 2018
```

Why am I getting different timezones here?

Comment: Probably as it's using your default Locale and the Uk switches between timezones in accordance with the date.

Comment: yes same formatter, @d.j.brown how can I solve this so both dates are always in GMT?

Comment: `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: Better to use UTC than GMT - the intent is much clearer. Note that it's not that the UK "switches between time zones" - it's that the Europe/London time zone switches between GMT and BST over time.

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet is UTC effectively always the same as +0000?

Comment: that has worked @d.j.brown , if you answer I can accept it

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for being more technically correct

Comment: You are using the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Any particular reason? I recommend you throw it out and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead. It is much nicer to work with. And will not show the surprising behaviour you have experienced.

Comment: In other words, BST is not a time zone. I suppose in this context it means British Summer Time, which can be considered half a time zone (BST may also mean Bangladesh Standard Time and Bougainville Standard Time and more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-30T13:00:00+0000" )
```

## java.time

Among the many design flaws of the troublesome old legacy classes you are using is that the `Date::toString` method applies your JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string. So while the value internally is actually in UTC, it confusingly appears to have another time zone. Add to that that your current default time zone experiences a Daylight Saving Time cutover between your two dates.

Instead use modern java.time classes. Parse your input strings as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) objects.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-30T13:00:00+0000" ) ;
```

A bug in Java 8 and Java 9 might bite on parsing your offset-from-UTC lacking a colon between hours and minutes. As a workaround, add the colon.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-30T13:00:00+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ;
```

Call `toString` to generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format. Result is *not* adulterated by any time zone dynamically applied, unlike `Date`.

If desired, assign a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

See [complete code for both inputs run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/PRQnPG).

```
String input2017 = "2017-01-30T13:00:00+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ;  // Workaround Java 8 bug where omitted colon in offset-from-UTC fails to parse. Fixed in Java 9.
OffsetDateTime odt2017 = OffsetDateTime.parse( input2017 ) ; 

String input2018 = "2018-06-23T16:00:00+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ;  // Workaround Java 8 bug where omitted colon in offset-from-UTC fails to parse. Fixed in Java 9.
OffsetDateTime odt2018 = OffsetDateTime.parse( input2018 ) ; 

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt2017 = odt2017.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt2018 = odt2018.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input2017: " + input2017 ) ;
System.out.println( "odt2017: " + odt2017 ) ;
System.out.println( "zdt2017: " + zdt2017 ) ;
System.out.println( "" ) ;  // Blank line.

System.out.println( "input2018: " + input2018 ) ;
System.out.println( "odt2018: " + odt2018 ) ;
System.out.println( "zdt2018: " + zdt2018 ) ;
```

Note how in June 2018, `Europe/London` time jumps forward an hour because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). In winter, London zone is on UTC but in summer, one hour *ahead* of UTC.

### 2017

> input2017: 2017-01-30T13:00:00+00:00
>
> odt2017: 2017-01-30T13:00Z
>
> zdt2017: 2017-01-30T13:00Z[Europe/London]

### 2018

> input2018: 2018-06-23T16:00:00+00:00
>
> odt2018: 2018-06-23T16:00Z
>
> zdt2018: 2018-06-23T17:00+01:00[Europe/London]

Search Stack Overflow for much more info as this topic has been handled many many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. Typo fixed. Thanks.